# How to get number of samples from wav file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wav

I know that I can do `soxi file.wav` to get info such as

```
Input File     : '2.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 8000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:04:14.54 = 2036320 samples ~ 19090.5 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 4.07M
Bit Rate       : 128k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

Where I can see that it has `2036320 samples`. However how do I do the same thing in python?

I have tried this through reading some articles but I keep getting `<bound method Wave_read.readframes of <wave.Wave_read instance at...`

```
import wave

audio_file = wave.open(wavfile, 'r')
print(audio_file.readframes)
audio_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `getnframes()` method instead of `readframes`